# getting null pointer exception when invoking an adapter from Java

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

i am getting null pointer exception when i want to invoke adapter from java class

in this below line is the error and not getting the object of `DataAccessService`

```
DataAccessService dataAces = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();
```

Comment: Why don't you add the exception to the question...?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share much info, but your code should look something like the below with proper modification where applied (adapter name, procedure name, parameters and so on):

```
import com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject;
import com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightBundles;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.DataAccessService;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.InvocationResult;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.ProcedureQName;

public void callProcedure() {
    DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();
    String paramArray = "['param1', 'param2', 'param3']";
    ProcedureQName procedureQName = new ProcedureQName("adapterName",
"procedureName");
    InvocationResult result = service.invokeProcedure(procedureQName,paramArray);
    JSONObject jsonObject = result.toJSON();
    String value = (String)jsonObject.get("key");
}
```